# Splitting 1 column of CSV into multiple columns based on UIDs per animal ID

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to take one specific column in a .csv file and split the values into new columns that are output to a new file. The columns are specimen UIDs. In some instances I have multiple UIDs per animal that I want split into new columns. for example: if my column has 3 UIDs per animal I want to transpose each UID into its own column then do the same for every animal so that each of the three generated columns have 1 UID per animal. currently I am copying every 3rd UID and pasting it by hand.

At the moment. my script is generating new columns based on the # of UIDS per animal, but it is not appending the file or splitting the values from the original column. I'm a bit out of practice so any help would be appreciated!

```
import csv

def split_column(input_file, output_file, uids_per_animal):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        rows = list(reader)

        headers = rows[0]
        column_to_split = [row[1] for row in rows[1:]]  # Extract the second column to split
        animal_ids = [row[2] for row in rows[1:]]  # Extract the animal ID column

        new_headers = headers[:2]  # Keep the first two column headers

        for i in range(uids_per_animal):
            new_headers.append(f"UID_{i+1}")  # Generate new column headers

        new_rows = [new_headers]

        for i in range(len(column_to_split)):
            animal_id = animal_ids[i]
            uids = column_to_split[i].split(',')  # Split the column values by comma

            num_splits = (len(uids) + uids_per_animal - 1) // uids_per_animal  # Calculate number of splits

            for j in range(num_splits):
                new_row = [animal_id]

                for k in range(uids_per_animal):
                    index = j * uids_per_animal + k
                    if index < len(uids):
                        new_row.append(uids[index])
                    else:
                        new_row.append('')  # Fill empty values if there are fewer UIDs

                new_rows.append(new_row)

    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerows(new_rows)

# Example usage
input_file = input("Enter input file name: ")
output_file = input("Enter output file name: ")
uids_per_animal = int(input("Enter the number of UIDs per Animal ID: "))

split_column(input_file, output_file, uids_per_animal)
print(f"The second column has been split into {uids_per_animal} columns in the output file.")
```

Input example: (this is what is downloaded from out management system)

Day,UID,Animal_ID
1,1000,H0001
1,1001,H0001
1,1002,H0002
1,1003,H0002
1,1004,H0003
1,1005,H0003

Output example: (I will use this to more efficiently add the UIDs to a separate checklist)

Day,Animal_ID,UID_1,UID_2
1,H0001,1000,1001
1,H0002,1002,1003
1,H0003,1004,1005

one column for each UID in the event that there are more than 2 UIDs per animal.

Comment: Could you give a minimal example of input data and desired result ? See [how to make a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include that small sample of the input CSV and the expected output CSV.  It's still not clear from your description what you're after; concrete examples really help. Thanks :)

Comment: I have edited the file to hopefully clarify it.